# Difference between: 有多少个 and 有几个

Tags: word-choice, difference

I would like to double check chat gpt`s answer with something more accurate:
My question below:

> 一年有多少个星期
> and
> 一年有几个星期?
> are different phrases but they mean the same, correct?
> Is there any grammar and meaning difference between the two?

ChatGPT:

> Yes, both phrases convey the same meaning, asking about the number of weeks in a year. > However, there are some differences in grammar and structure between the two phrases:
>
> 一年有多少个星期？(Yī nián yǒu duōshǎo gè xīngqī?)
>
> This is a more common and straightforward way to ask "How many weeks are there in a
> year?" The structure is similar to asking about the quantity of something.
> 一年有几个星期？(Yī nián yǒu jǐ gè xīngqī?)
>
> This phrase is also correct, but it uses "几" (jǐ), which is often used for smaller
> quantities or numbers that are not easily counted. In this context, it still works, but
> it might imply a slightly more casual or less precise tone compared to the first
> phrase.
> In summary, both phrases are correct and can be used interchangeably to ask about the
> number of weeks in a year, but the second one might be considered slightly more casual
> or less precise due to the use of "几."

Is chat gpt right?
Is it incomplete?
Is there something more on this topic that a chinese as a second language might need to know?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not 多小个 but 多少个. Other than that, GPT largely covers it all. Remember to replace 个 with other measurement words, when required by the following noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

多小 is wrong, 多少 is correct.

I think chat gpt is right. 几 is more casual and often used in oral Chinese.

If you need to write an article, use 多少 is better, more formal.

(experience from student： If you need to make up the word count for an article, use "多少"，this word has one more character.  XD）

In daily use, there is not much difference between these two words.
But in oral conversation, sometimes the measure words are ignored.
Like these case, use 多少

How many games have you played？
你玩过多少游戏√   你玩过几游戏×

How many snacks did you eat tonight？
你今晚吃了多少零食√  你今晚吃了几零食×

https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1642080912001974761&wfr=spider&for=pc I found an article on Baidu, this can help

Answer (score 2):

有多少 = how many (approximately)?

有几个 = how many (exactly)?

The former is used to quantify something, for which the exact number is less certain, or not as important.

Answer (score 1):

**有多少个** and **有几个** are widely used in questions, and they have the same meaning in most of the cases.

But **多少** and **几** cannot be substituted for each other in many cases. For example:

(1) 你有**多少**人马? - How many troops do you have? NOT 你有**几**人马?

(2) 有**多少**钱够你这样浪费啊? - How much money is enough for you to waste like this? NOT 有**几**钱才够你这样浪费啊?